# load array of little images?

Tags: iphone

at the beginning of my program, my view loads several image from its resource folder such as

```
 NSArray *photos = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"]];
```

it works fine but I felt uncomfortable that I hold over 40 numbers of image on my resource folder because it looks messy and uncompleted. So I was kinda wondering is there any ways to hold images other way, such as core data, or storing images on the folder which is only for the images. please give me some idea :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first thing is nil is missing in your code

```
NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"],nil];
```

Second you can create a group named images or folder in your projects directory then add that folder directly to your project. Copy all the images into that folder and add using the add existing files. Do not check copy resources option. I manage things like this.